# go mod vendor without update to latest

Tags: go, go-modules

I’m trying to figure out if it’s possible to run go mod vendor without the go tool updating my go.mod file.

I specifically `go get package/subpackage@commit` and commit my `go.mod` with the correct version.

Then I run `go mod vendor` and it automatically bumps the version of the package that I just specifically set.

I’ve looked at this page to no avail: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away

I need to use vendor because I run a script that edits some of the vendored deps., I’m looking at the following build flow:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get package/subpackge@commit
GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
./Script/patch_vendors.sh --write
GO111MODULE=off go build
```

My other option is modifying the copied source wherever go mod vendor donwloads it to, but
not sure how to approach that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `go -mod=readonly mod vendor`.

Comment: Thank you; will do had found this document: https://github.com/thepudds/go-module-knobs/blob/master/README.md but it only mentions that that flag applies to `go build`

Comment: `go mod` used to ignore the `-mod` flag. I'm not sure if that changed by now.

Answer (score 4):

Per https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Maintaining_module_requirements:

> The `go` command itself automatically updates the `go.mod` file to maintain a standard formatting and the accuracy of `require` statements.
>
> Any go command that finds an unfamiliar import will look up the module containing that import and add the latest version of that module to go.mod automatically. […]
>
> Any go command can determine that a module requirement is missing and must be added […].

The `go mod vendor` command copies in all of the transitive imports of your packages and their tests, so it will automatically update the `go.mod` file to ensure that all of the imported packages are present.

So the problem here is likely that the `commit` you've selected for `package/subpackage` fails to provide some package that appears in the transitive imports of your program. If that is correct, you should find that `go list all`, `go test all`, and `go mod tidy` all make that same edit to your module's requirements.