# How to prevent from `go build` to update the latest version of modules

Tags: go, go-build

I am using an open source project called "[yaegi](http://github.com/traefik/yaegi)" in a large project.

I need to use older version of "yaegi": `v.0.8.11`, so I modified the `go.mod` file and replaced:
`github.com/traefik/yaegi v0.9.2 // indirect` with `github.com/containous/yaegi v0.8.11`
But when I build the project, it starts to update all the modules and replace it back to the most updated version:

```
root@ubuntu:~/myproj1# go build main.go
go: finding module for package github.com/traefik/yaegi/stdlib/unsafe
go: finding module for package github.com/traefik/yaegi/stdlib
go: finding module for package github.com/traefik/yaegi/interp
go: found github.com/traefik/yaegi/interp in github.com/traefik/yaegi v0.9.2
```

How can I prevent it and keep it using the old version `v.0.8.11`?
I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331859/2153777) that according to https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Maintaining_module_requirements:

> The `go` command itself automatically updates the `go.mod` file to maintain a standard formatting and the accuracy of `require` statements.
>
> Any go command that finds an unfamiliar import will look up the module containing that import and add the latest version of that module to go.mod automatically. […]
>
> Any go command can determine that a module requirement is missing and must be added […].

Maybe there is a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 5):

`//indirect` in `go.mod` means that at least one of your other modules you’re importing is dependent on that version of module, therefore `go build` shall automatically update that module, no matter how you changed that line in your `go.mod`. In your case if you don’t want to use `yaegi` module of `v0.9.2` you have to first get rid of other dependencies dependent on that module from your project, and then fix your `go.mod` to make your project require `yaegi v0.8.11`. You can just delete them or make them require earlier version of `yaegi` by using their older version or editing their source code. Also, instead of editing `go.mod` directly, I’d run something like `go get -v github.com/containous/yaegi@0.8.11` to checkout to a specific version of a module.